# How to get Android Application Name displayed in Advanced Task Killer instead of package name?

Tags: android

Mine displays as the xxx.xxx.com package name.  Where do I set a property/attribute/whatever so that it will display the actual app name like the rest of the apps in the list?

Comment: Also, to get application icon to show in the list instead of generic green guy?

Comment: Post the code you have in your manifest, so we can see if you have any errors there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this before the 1st "activity" in my manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name=".BroadcastSMSApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: The label did the trick for correcting the name in ATK.  Also, I redid my icon as a 72x72 instead of 48x48 and that seemed to fix the icon in ATK list as well.  Thanks!

Comment: @333Matt if that worked the upvote and check mark are much appreciated.